# jekyll not generating _posts

Tags: ruby, jekyll, rdiscount

I'm have trouble getting jekyll to convert a post in _posts directory to html. It generates index.md correctly, but doesn't generate anything for posts. When I add 'source: _posts' then it converts the post, but doesn't convert index.md.

As far as I can tell, 'source' should either be not added to _config.yml to should point to '.'

My directory structure is pretty standard:

```
$ find .|fgrep -v bootstrap
.
./index.md
./_config.yml
./_drafts
./_includes
./_includes/footer.html
./_includes/header.html
./_layouts
./_layouts/default.html
./_posts
./_posts/2013--02-25-test-blog.md
./_site
./_site/index.html
```

```
$ cat _config.yml
name: "Developer blog"
description: ""

url: "http://localhost:4000"
source: .
paginate: 10

markdown: rdiscount
permalink: pretty
pygments: true
auto: true
```

Even when I leave auto off, I see no stack traces.

```
$ cat _posts/2013--02-25-test-blog.md
---
layout: default
title: Testing a blog
---

#test blog

this is a test
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
_posts/2013--02-25-test-blog.md
```

This name is not correct.

Perhaps use this

```
_posts/2013-02-25-test-blog.md
```

Notice carefully only 1 hyphen after the year.