# Jekyll post not generated

Tags: jekyll

I am trying to add a new post to my Jekyll site, but I cannot see it on the generated pages when I run `jekyll serve`.

What are some common reasons for a Jekyll post to not be generated?

Comment: When using collections folder, put the _post folder in your collections directory. https://github.com/jekyll/jekyll/issues/6702

Comment: When you change the `collections_dir` in your config from `.` to `my_col_folder` all your posts have to move as well below `my_col_folder/_posts` https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/default/ -> this is such a strange behavior!

Answer (score 270, accepted):

- **The post is not placed in the** `_posts` **directory.**
- When you change the `collections_dir` in your config from `.` (default) to `my_col_folder` all your posts have to move as well below `my_col_folder/_posts` [jekyll defaults](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/default/)
- [**The post has incorrect title.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15046420/jekyll-not-generating-posts) Posts should be named `YEAR-MONTH-DAY-title.MARKUP` (*Note the `MARKUP` extension*, which is usually `.md` or `.markdown`)
- **The post's date is in the future.** You can make the post visible by setting `future: true` in `_config.yml` [(documentation)](https://jekyllrb.com/docs/configuration/#build-command-options)
- [**The post has** `published: false` **in its front matter.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16990138/jekyll-not-generating-posts) Set it to `true`.
- <s>[**The title contains a** `:` **character.**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10963002/jekyll-new-posts-not-being-generated) Replace it with `&#58`.</s> *Works in jekyll `3.8.3` (and probably in other 'recent' releases).*

Comment: using `future:true` without any space after `:` in `_config,yml` leads to ERR: Configuration file: (INVALID). `future: true` most be used instead.

Comment: Another possible reason is because of forgetting to add the `.markdown` extension to the filename. I know this because I've just wasted 5 minutes of my life because of it.

Comment: Thank you so much! Just searched 30 minutes why my post wasn't showing up until I understood that there's a date filter ... (in 15mins it would work "magically"...). Added the future option and everything works as expected. true should be default in my opinion.

Comment: The same for me: had a post under `_drafts` promote it to `_posts` and it disapperead. 30 minutes to understand it: page in `_drafts` folder doesn't need date in the title, page under `_posts` need it... Thank you!

Comment: When apply `future: true` you may need to stop and start your Jekyll server for the change to take effect.

Comment: What am I missing. My post here has a colon in the title and it's ok? https://raw.githubusercontent.com/alexharv074/alexharv074.github.io/master/_posts/2016-05-08-setting-up-puppet-module-testing-from-scratch-part-i-puppet-syntax-puppet-lint-and-rspec-puppet.md  and it appears ok here? https://alexharv074.github.io

Comment: @AlexHarvey Thanks for the comment! This indeed seems to not be a problem anymore. I updated my answer.

Comment: This is why you should read Jekyll docs before doing a post scheduler like [this](https://github.com/uta-org/jekyll-scheduler).

Answer (score 25):

You can use `jekyll build --verbose` to view build process in detail.

Exmaple output:

```
  Logging at level: debug
Configuration file: /home/fangxing/fffx.github.io/_config.yml
  Logging at level: debug
         Requiring: jekyll-archives
         Requiring: jekyll-livereload
         Requiring: kramdown
            Source: /home/fangxing/fffx.github.io
       Destination: /home/fangxing/fffx.github.io/_site
 Incremental build: enabled
      Generating... 
       EntryFilter: excluded /Gemfile
       EntryFilter: excluded /Gemfile.lock
           Reading: _posts/2018-01-14-new-post.md
           Reading: _posts/2014-01-01-example-content.md
           Reading: _posts/2014-01-02-introducing-lanyon.md
           Reading: _posts/2017-11-21-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown
           Reading: _posts/2018-01-14-boot-android-on-charge.md
           Reading: _posts/2013-12-31-whats-jekyll.md
          Skipping: _posts/2018-01-14-boot-android-on-charge.md has a future date
        Generating: Jekyll::Archives::Archives finished in 0.000122873 seconds.
        Generating: JekyllFeed::Generator finished in 0.000468846 seconds.
        ...
```

from the  log I found jeklly skipped `2018-01-14-boot-android-on-charge.md` because it has a future date.

Answer (score 9):

One possible reason is that the `date` specified in the front matter does not contain a time zone offset, in which case it defaults to UTC, not the time zone of the local machine as you might expect. I wasted an hour on this until UTC "caught up" with my current local time zone, BST.

I haven't found a definitive answer to this but I think the date in the front matter must be given in UTC with a timezone offset (which defaults to zero if omitted).

So `date: 2018-05-03 12:34:27` **is in UTC** irrespective of where in the world you are, and irrespective of the `timezone` setting in `_config.yml`.

So be careful to specify datetimes like this:

```
date: 2018-05-03 12:34:27 +0100
```

Comment: The format `date: 2018-05-03 12:34:27 +01:30` also seems to work. Note the additional colon.

Comment: Wasted 10 mins to realise this was the issue. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Or it can be browser cache as well if you are looking not in the *_site* folder but directly on the blog's main page with the list of posts.

Answer (score 2):

I have written Rspec tests for my blog that express these rules:

```rb
require 'spec_helper'
require 'yaml'

# Documented at https://jekyllrb.com/news/2017/03/02/jekyll-3-4-1-released/
post_regex = %r!^(?:.+/)*(\d{2,4}-\d{1,2}-\d{1,2})-(.*)(\.[^.]+)$!

def date_in_front_matter(date)
  return date if date.is_a?(Date)
  return date.to_date if date.is_a?(Time)
  return Date.parse(date) if date.is_a?(String)
end

describe 'posts' do
  Dir.glob("_posts/*md").each do |file|
    basename = File.basename(file)

    context basename do
      front_matter = YAML.load(File.read(file).split(/---/)[1])

      it 'filename must match documented post regex' do
        expect(basename).to match post_regex
      end

      it 'date in file name same day as date in front matter' do
        date_in_file_name = Date.parse(post_regex.match(basename).captures[0])
        expect(date_in_front_matter(front_matter['date'])).to eq date_in_file_name
      end

      it 'title in front matter should not contain a colon' do
        expect(front_matter['title']).to_not match /:/
      end

      it 'front matter should not have published: false' do
        expect(front_matter['published']).to_not be false
      end
    end
  end
end
```

This may be of use to others as I was losing a lot of time due to typos in the date etc.

These tests along with the rest of the Rspec config can be seen in context [here](https://github.com/alexharv074/alexharv074.github.io/blob/master/spec/validate_spec.rb).

Answer (score 2):

Just to add one more reason, when you move an article from `_drafts` to `_post`, you sometimes need to delete the `_site` for the article to be regenerated.

In my case it often happens that `_site` will not be entirely deleted before re-generation so the new article won't appear.

Anyway `rm -rf _site` and `bundle exec jekyll serve` works :)

Answer (score 1):

If you have checked your front matter, and all seems well, and even `jekyll build --verbose` doesn't reveal anything (in my case, it just acted as if the file didn't exist at all, not even listing it as excluded), check the encoding of your file. Apparently, it needs to be `UTF-8` without signature. It it's `UTF-8 BOM` (or `UTF-8 with Signature` as some text editors call it), then it will be silently ignored. To make matters worse, some editors will display both types as just `UTF-8`, making the difference even harder to spot.

Answer (score 1):

If you are unable to track the file in `--verbose` and if the file is silently ignored then try removing `collections_dir` in the `config.yml` file. That solved the issue for me.

Answer (score 0):

My post also did not appear an the error was, that in my name I used a dot, e.g. `2017-10-18-test.2.md`.
This is not accepted, you have to use `2017-10-18-test2.md`.

Answer (score 0):

In my case I had enabled incremental build which caused this issue, make sure to check it.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/34686814)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).