# Jekyll Blog not updating / showing new posts

Tags: jekyll, github-pages

After I read through all the questions I found here, I still don't get my blog Atmochrom.com running

You can find my repository right here: https://github.com/MarcLeyendecker/marcleyendecker.github.io

I did not change anything. Actually I always duplicate my latest post, edit the .markdown file and push it to the repository. Working for over a year now this way, now it just fails to show the updated site. 
Any ideas what I could do?

I already...

- checked the config
- checked the CNAME
- checked the index

Really hope you can help me!

Comment: looks like it is working to me - is there a post missing still? GH recently updated to jekyll 3 and I think there was a change to the way future dates worked, maybe your post filename included a date that was in the future and was not being displayed because of that?

Comment: This  is happening probably due to Jekyll 3 upgrade by GitHub. Mostly, it affected: markdown, highlighter and some gems like jekyll-pagination. Search here on Stack Overflow for `[jekyll]` and you'll find some recent questions and answers related to that. If you can't solve the issue by yourself, edit your question adding your `_config. yml` and your `Gemfile` if you already have one and we can assist you in this matter. ;)

Answer (score 8):

Marc, just double check ...

1. your post markdown is clean
2. there are no untracked files when you push to git
3. This post can help [What are some common reasons for a Jekyll post to not be generated?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30625044/jekyll-post-not-generated)

This tip helped `future: true`