# Blog posts are not showing in Jekyll?

Tags: ruby, github, jekyll, github-pages

I have created a blog using Jekyll now theme. And I've created repo in github to publish the blog. But the posts are not showing in github pages.

repo: https://github.com/mubumbz/blog

blog: http://mubumbz.github.io/blog/

Comment: Did you build out the pages before pushing back to your repo?

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30625044/jekyll-post-not-generated. Your post date was in the future. Set you time_zone in _config.yml and republish.

Answer (score 2):

In my case the blog post time was a future date (due to timezone mismatch) hence it was not published though _posts folder had my markdown file

executing 'jekyll build' will give the same message

```
sachinms@MS:/my-new-blog/my-personal-blog$ jekyll build
Configuration file: /my-new-blog/my-personal-blog/_config.yml
 Theme Config file: /home/sachinms/gems/gems/jekyll-theme-chirpy-4.0.1/_config.yml
            Source: /my-new-blog/my-personal-blog
       Destination: /my-new-blog/my-personal-blog/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating...
          Skipping: _posts/2021-07-17-Minimal-API-ASPNET-6.md has a future date
                    done in 0.38 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: disabled. Use --watch to enable.
```

Answer (score 0):

you must post added _post directory and post name must be year-mouth-day-post_name.md format
after  on the blog main directory run command **bundle exec jekyll build** or **jekyll build** and push remote repo.