# Jekyll post not showing up on github pages but does show up on http://127.0.0.1:4000/

Tags: jekyll

Running `jekyll serve` I do see the post at localhost

```
http://127.0.0.1:4000/
Blog Posts
01 Jun 2016 » Python + R = Simpler life
26 May 2016 » Hello world!
26 Apr 2016 » Scraping flashcards for Anki with Python
```

but after committing the post doesn't appear on my github pages!

```
http://rainymood.github.io/

Blog Posts
26 May 2016 » Hello world!
26 Apr 2016 » Scraping flashcards for Anki with Python
```

I did some across [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30625044/jekyll-post-not-generated) so I checked everything.

The post is in the `_posts` directory named `2016-06-02-Python-R-combine.markdown`, see Github

The post has correct title. Posts should be named YEAR-MONTH-DAY-title.MARKUP

The post's date is in the past:

```
---
layout: post
title:  "Python + R = Simpler life"
date:   2016-06-01 15:00:00 +0200
categories: jekyll update
---

## R 

In this post I want to show how I use Python to make my life a little bit easier
sometimes. For my MSc thesis I am working in R and dealing with a large amount
of technical indicators which I calculate in R as follows
```

The post does not have `published: false` in its front matter. Nor does the title contain a `:`. Does anyone have an idea why my post is showing up on localhost but not on my Github pages?

edit: *SOLVED* In creating `analytics.html` I copied `page-header.html` as a base but forgot to rename it to `analytics.html` after I was done editing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you go to [your settings page](https://github.com/Rainymood/rainymood.github.io/settings), in the Github Pages, you will see :

> Your site is having problems building: A file was included in _includes/head.html, that is a symlink or does not exist in your _includes directory. For more information, see https://help.github.com/articles/page-build-failed-file-is-a-symlink.

Copy paste your local `analytics.html` in your `_include` folder, push, and everything will be ok.

Comment: Thank you very much! Instantly solved my problem. When I was creating the analytics file I copied a file to use as a base but then forgot to rename it to `analytics.html`.