# Jekyll is not reading new posts

Tags: jekyll

I'm trying to add new posts to my jekyll site. But when I execute "jekyll serve --verbose" I see my new posts are not read by jekyll. I have looked all questions similar to my problem but they didn't work for my case.

My new post names are *2018-04-18-first.markdown* and *2019-04-17-second.markdown* but jekyll tries to read default post whic is *2020-04-18-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown*

Putting verbose log below.

```
Logging at level: debug
Configuration file: /home/dozturk/50percent/_config.yml
         Requiring: kramdown
            Source: /home/dozturk/50percent
       Destination: /home/dozturk/50percent/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating...
           Reading: _posts/2020-04-18-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown
         Rendering: _posts/2020-04-18-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown
  Pre-Render Hooks: _posts/2020-04-18-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown
  Rendering Liquid: _posts/2020-04-18-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown
         Requiring: rouge
  Rendering Markup: _posts/2020-04-18-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown
         Requiring: kramdown
  Rendering Layout: _posts/2020-04-18-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown
         Rendering: _posts/2020-04-18-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown
  Pre-Render Hooks: _posts/2020-04-18-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown
  Rendering Liquid: _posts/2020-04-18-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown
  Rendering Markup: _posts/2020-04-18-welcome-to-jekyll.markdown
         Rendering: about.md
  Pre-Render Hooks: about.md
  Rendering Liquid: about.md
  Rendering Markup: about.md
  Rendering Layout: about.md
         Rendering: feed.xml
  Pre-Render Hooks: feed.xml
  Rendering Liquid: feed.xml
  Rendering Markup: feed.xml
  Rendering Layout: feed.xml
         Rendering: index.html
  Pre-Render Hooks: index.html
  Rendering Liquid: index.html
  Rendering Markup: index.html
  Rendering Layout: index.html
         Rendering: /css/main.scss
  Pre-Render Hooks: /css/main.scss
  Rendering Liquid: /css/main.scss
  Rendering Markup: /css/main.scss
                    done in 0.222 seconds.
         Requiring: jekyll-watch
         Requiring: kramdown
           Watcher: Ignoring (?-mix:_config\.yml)
           Watcher: Ignoring (?-mix:_site)
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for '/home/dozturk/50percent'
  Logging at level: debug
Configuration file: /home/dozturk/50percent/_config.yml
[2020-04-18 22:12:15] INFO  WEBrick 1.4.2
[2020-04-18 22:12:15] INFO  ruby 2.5.1 (2018-03-29) [x86_64-linux-gnu]
[2020-04-18 22:12:15] DEBUG WEBrick::HTTPServlet::FileHandler is mounted on /.
[2020-04-18 22:12:15] DEBUG unmount .
[2020-04-18 22:12:15] DEBUG Jekyll::Commands::Serve::Servlet is mounted on .
    Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000/
[2020-04-18 22:12:15] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start: pid=3784 port=4000
  Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
^C[2020-04-18 22:18:36] DEBUG close TCPSocket(127.0.0.1, 4000)
[2020-04-18 22:18:36] INFO  going to shutdown ...
[2020-04-18 22:18:36] INFO  WEBrick::HTTPServer#start done.
```

[Solved]
Today I tried building again and it built successfully first and second posts as I wanted. I was duplicating and renaming posts from Windows Explorer to create new posts. Today I realized Ubuntu doesn't detect changes that I made in Windows Explorer, probably the core of the problem is that. Everything seems like working now!

Comment: Have a look at https://stackoverflow.com/a/30625045/1548376 and https://stackoverflow.com/a/50155381/1548376

Comment: Thank you. As I said, I have already looked at them. Today I tried building again and it built successfully first and second posts as I wanted. I was duplicating and renaming posts from Windows Explorer to create new posts. Today I realized Ubuntu doesn't detect changes that I made in Windows Explorer, probably the core of the problem is that. Everything seems like working now!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Today I tried building again and it built successfully first and second posts as I wanted. I was duplicating and renaming posts from Windows Explorer to create new posts. Today I realized Ubuntu doesn't detect changes that I made in Windows Explorer, probably the core of the problem is that. Everything seems like working now!

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you add the front matter tag(Two lines of three dashes ("-")). Like this:

```
---
---
(Rest of your content)
```

Frontmatter tells Jekyll to process and convert the page.
https://jekyllrb.com/docs/front-matter/

Comment: Thank you. Frontmatter wasn't the problem. Today I tried building again and it built successfully first and second posts as I wanted. I was duplicating and renaming posts from Windows Explorer to create new posts. Today I realized Ubuntu doesn't detect changes that I made in Windows Explorer, probably the core of the problem is that. Everything seems like working now!