# Jekyll blog posts not showing up on github pages

Tags: html, jekyll, github-pages

I've used Jekyll to build my website and it works as intended locally. However, when I deploy my website to [github pages](https://github.com/jialun-zhang/jialun-zhang.github.io), the blog posts no longer show up.

I have consulted a previous question:  [Jekyll post not generated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30625044/jekyll-post-not-generated), but it did not solve my problems.

When I do `bundle exec jekyll serve` locally, i get the following message

```
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
       Jekyll Feed: Generating feed for posts
         AutoPages: Disabled/Not configured in site.config.
        Pagination: Complete, processed 1 pagination page(s)
                    done in 6.303 seconds.
```

which seem to indicate that everything is working ok. What is the problem?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If everything is right you will have a message with an information that your server is running afaik.

For example this is my message (note last line):

```
$ bundle exec jekyll serve
Configuration file: /Users/alexfreik/Documents/GitHub/ltc-webpage/_config.yml
            Source: /Users/alexfreik/Documents/GitHub/ltc-webpage
       Destination: /Users/alexfreik/Documents/GitHub/ltc-webpage/_site
 Incremental build: disabled. Enable with --incremental
      Generating... 
       Jekyll Feed: Generating feed for posts
                    done in 0.94 seconds.
 Auto-regeneration: enabled for '/Users/alexfreik/Documents/GitHub/ltc-webpage'
    Server address: http://127.0.0.1:4000/
  Server running... press ctrl-c to stop.
```

Do you have this information?

**EDIT**: The problem was in the incorrectly set pagination.

Comment: Yes. My message looks similar to yours. Everything is ok when I run jekyll locally. But the blog posts disappear when I deploy to github pages.

Comment: Can you add `gem "github-pages"` in your `group :jekyll_plugins` in the `Gemfile`?

Comment: Indeed. It seems you have some problems with your pagination. When I replaced `for post in paginator.posts` with `for post in site.posts` (and tested in my GitHub repo-clone of your website) the post have appeared at GitHub pages

Comment: maybe will be of any help https://jekyllrb.com/docs/pagination/ . I skimmed through this docs and found some warning 
`Don't set a permalink
Setting a permalink in the front matter of your blog page will cause pagination to break. Just omit the permalink.`

And it seems that you are using permalinks. 

Also I have skimmed through GitHub Actions build log, and found particularly interesting line
`Pagination: Pagination is enabled, but I couldn't find an index.html page to use as the pagination template. Skipping pagination.`. It seems that it is the root of problems

Comment: This error was logged when I replaced permalink with `pagination_path` so maybe I just broke something when replaced the permalink line)))

Comment: Getting rid of the permalink and changing to site.posts instead of paginator.posts actually fixed the problem. Thank you very much!

Comment: No problem, ahah) but it seems that you wanted this pagination functionality so you still need to debug this )